# Отправить текст в другую активити

Tags: android

Есть 2 поля `EditText` - "Кому отправить", "Что отправить" и `Button` - "Send". Нужно, чтобы по клику на "Send" текст отправлялся в другое `Activity`  и плюсовалась первая строка к второй. Например "Кому отправить" - Роме, "Что отправить"- Привет.

Не могу написать нормальный обработчик событий чтобы плюсовало `textView` и выводило в другом `activity`.

Ниже пример кода.

```
package com.example.user.changeactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void OnCLick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Вставил код в тело вопроса, он не динамичен, не вытягивает инфу из строк.

Comment: В общем о этот код ВООБЩЕ ничего не делает. Где, собственно, то , что шлет ваши строки и пытается их соединить ? вы предлагаете написать их кому то за вас?

Comment: через `bundle` в `Intnet` передавайте необходимые данные. а так ваш код, как сказал @pavlofff, ничего не делает.

Comment: Извините, ошибся с окном. Поменял код на Main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из первой активити в обработчике события отправляете намерение с данными которые хотите передать:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("message", user + ", вам передали: " + gift);
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

В **SecondActivity** в методе **onCreate** извлекаете данные из вызывающего намерения:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringEtra("message");
infoTextView.setText(message);
```

Только не забудь перед этим проверить передавались ли с намерением данные:

```
if(intent.hasExtra("message")) {
    // Извлекаем message
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Данные переменные необходимо объявить в самой активити, а не в методе onCreate и сделать их статическими

```
  public static  String user = "Рома";
  public static  String gift = "Привет";
```

Тогда к ним можно будет обратиться по имени активити и переменной например:

```
    TextView infoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewInfo);
    infoTextView.setText(SecondActivity.user + " , вам передали " + SecondActivity.gift);
```

Comment: Очень плохая практика. Активити, не отображаемая на экране, в любое время может быть уничтожена и обращение к ее полям вызовет NPE. При статических полях, создание статических объектов с ссылками из других объектов приведет к утечкам памяти, что тоже плохая практика.

Comment: Для данного примера подойдет. Начинающему будет сложнее понять SharedPreferences или intent.putExtra

Comment: Ну так чтобы перейти из разряда "начинающих" надо заниматься такими вопросами, а не с каждым новым и непонятным вопросом идти на форум и просить решения.

Comment: @temq, да, я понимаю что вопросы мои глупы, но как раз таки самое важно это научиться делать простейшие шаги. Это как учиться ходить, как только научишься то уже можешь куда-то идти. Ну не нашел я нигде как можно плюсовать строки и выводить в другое окно. Поэтому и зарегистрировался тут, я никогда в жизни не программировал но хочу научиться, что плохого в этом? Если вы порекомендуете литературу или что-то в этом роде - буду благодарен.

Comment: @Romikromikromik про конкатенацию строк можно почитать здесь - http://habrahabr.ru/post/260767/, передача данных в другую активити - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html . Все это гуглится достаточно легко.

Comment: @Romikromikromik Вот еще про то, почему не надо делать так, как написано в этом ответе - http://habrahabr.ru/post/261721/

Comment: @pavlofff , спасибо я уже разобрался, с этим вопросом,все намного проще если не тупить) но статейка очень свежая, за что отдельное спасибо, приятно удивлен) сам подписан на фейсбуке на хабрахабр и утром ее как раз проглядывал, а тут еще Вы обо мне вспомнили и решили дать почитать) грац